# JQuery $.post using Spring in Java EE

Tags: java, jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I would like to use the `$.post` function of the jQuery library. I am currently working in a Java EE project using the framework Spring (first time doing that). I would like to know if it is possible with Spring to make an SQL query without reloading my page using this `$.post` function.

If you have a simple architecture to offer me with, I will be pleased to see it:

- controller: what should be here
- dao: what should be here
- xml configuration: what should be here
- jsp: what should be here

Indeed I looked on the web, and I found different kind of solutions using JSP and Servlets, but I don't really get how to do the same thing with Spring.
Here is an example I found :

- [Example of JQuery $.post with Spring in JavaEE](http://www.java4s.com/jquery-tutorials/submit-form-without-refreshing-page-in-javajsp-with-jquery/)

Comment: Yes, it is. Beyond that, do some research into AJAX, and then try some code. If you run into problems, ask a specific question and we'll do our best to help.

Comment: I would be delighted to try some some code. But I want to use JQuery and not AJAX. For know I didn't found what I wanted in the web for doing it (example) that's why I am trying to get here so clues. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had big trouble to understand what I needed to use hibernate, spring and JQuery. The thing was that I had to :

- Create a file with my content in JSP in web-inf file
- Define an xml layout where I put the definition of a variable used by the controller linked to the jsp file :

> ```
> <definition name="yourVariable" extends="yourTemplate">
>        <put-attribute name="contentName" value="/WEB-INF/tiles/contentFile.jsp"></put-attribute>   
> </definition>
> ```

- Create an entity with this kind of annotation : @Table(schema="dbo", name="tableNameInDB")
- Put the URI of the entity in a persistence file (xml)
- Create my dao :

  - StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("your query");
  - SQLQuery = getSession().createSQLQuery(sb.toString());
- Create the controller using a request mapping :

> ```
> @Inject
> YourDao yourModelVariable;//This call directly the DAO
> ```

```
@RequestMapping("/anyKinfOfStringYouWantToAcces")
@ResponseBody
public String execution() {     
    return yourModelVariable.getInfo();//It return the information you wanted from your dao (you can return any kind of type and info)
}
```

- Finally in your JSP, a classic jquery use :

> function actionGenerate(){
>           $.post("yourProjectRootURL/anyKinfOfStringYouWantToAcces", {},function(data){
>               $("#aFieldYouWantToChangeWithDataBaseWithoutReloadingPage").val(data);
>           });
>   }

If this work can help someone in the future ;), once you know the Key information like the @inject and things like that that become very powerfull.